# jquery not clear div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code for ajax load in my site

```
if (base === 'basic') {
    $.ajax({
        url: location,
        data: {},
        success: function (result) {
            document.title = titlepage;
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);
            $('#content').empty();
            $('#content').html('');
            $("#content").html(result);
        }
    });
} //if base
```

Everything work on it but not

```
$('#content').empty();
$('#content').html('');
```

How can I clear everything on

```
<div id="content">
```

So that I can load new things on it?
A lot of other div and other codes is in it.

Comment: Did you give some error from your debugger?

Comment: You probably should be doing either $('#content').empty(); or
$('#content').html(''); coz both does same work.Using .empty() would be a better option as no string parsing is involved. It operates directly on the DOM object model

Comment: if the content div contains other div in it you can use `$('#content').children().remove()` to remove all divs inside content div. or you can use `$('#content').children('#childrenId').empty()` to clear children content

Comment: i try anything please see [link]http://royta.ir/badurl and click on بازگشت به خانه its will load both pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2  tags with the same attribute value for the attribute ID. Which by HTML specification ID must be unique identificator.

```
<header>
    <div id="content"></div>
</header>
<section>
   <div id="content"></div>
</section>
```

So change the header div ID and you will be ready to go.

Comment: Yes he has 2 div with the same id 'content'. Sorry for previous comment.

Comment: Just open the source for the page he linked and you will see that he is using same id's [link](royta.ir/badurl)

Comment: this is my code so im sure im not have 2 div with id content <div id="content">
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['userid'])){
 include('content for user');
}else{
 include('register.page');
}

Comment: If you see the page you linked to us you have the same ID for the divs i posted at the top so see your html. [royta.ir/baddurl]

Comment: This accepted answer clearly points out why posters should post clear questions including markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#content").html(result);
```

will replace the existing data in `content` Div. so you do not have to worry about removing old info

Comment: but its not test it in [link]http://royta.ir/baddurl   and click on بازگشت به خانه

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: its 2 page both start with <div id="content"> and 1 page header included just 1 time everything must work but ...